# Divide 9×3 rect into 8 equal size square

Tags: math, puzzle, shapes

You whip up your favorite brownie recipe and pour into your new 9×3 inch baking dish. The brownies bake. The toothpick comes out clean. Now for the cutting.

A square is the most delicious shape for a brownie. You have eight people to serve. How can you cut your newly baked creation into exactly eight square pieces?

Comment: 8x 1in by 1in pieces, obviously.

Comment: @hkf: Did you understood the question correctly?

Comment: Into eight equal square pieces, 1x1 squares (when you actually mean cuboids) are equal, are they not?

Comment: @UPT: I think you may have misunderstood your question. It is only required that you form 8 square pieces, not 8 equal sized square pieces (as the title of your question implies...). I assume the original question can be found here: http://wordplay.blogs.nytimes.com/2012/04/30/numberplay-square/

Comment: @UPT While the question says that you want to cut the cake slice into 8 pieces, hkf's solution also solves the meta-problem of dealing with guests who are pissed off because of the size discrepancy of your servings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this is essentially a variation on a bin packing problem (which is well known to be `NP`-hard!).

One solution is to use 2 `3x3` squares, 1 `2x2` square and 5 `1x1` squares, as follows:

[image: 8 way packing]

The solution is obviously non-unique, since the positions of the various squares can be permuted around.

Due to the `NP`-hardness I imagine it would be difficult to come up with an efficient algorithm to divide a general `NxM` rectangle into `k` square pieces exactly. In fact there must be whole families of parameter values for which no solution is possible (for instance if you started with an `6x1` rectangle it would be impossible to divide into anything less than 6 squares...).